# Using different NS servers for each subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system

My current DNS is managed by CloudFlare, but sometimes I want to take more control on like url forwarding or use with samba for inhouse address resolution. How am I supposed to do this?

My Schema:

- domain.tld - managed by CF;
- roaming.domain.tld - managed by samba, for assigning jon.roaming.domain.tld / jane.roaming.domain.tld, etc.

I tried to add NS record     name.provider.tld to my domain, but and xyz.roaming on the dnspod control panel, but I still can not get A record on any client. Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Can you rewrite that using either all the same fake name or all the real domainname?  The mix of the two makes it hard to follow.

Comment: @Grant Sorry, I wasn't thinking it thorough. Now it's edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this - its called delegating a subdomain.

You basically just need an NS record for the subdomain in your domain's zone file that points to your in house dns server.

Look for guides ar your provider for delegating a subdomain.  Most have guides on the exact way to set it up in their control panels.

Comment: Unfortunately although it is possible to delegate subdomains with some providers, CloudFlare to not offer this functionality.

Comment: @BE77Y Yes, you can do this with CloudFlare. It will happily accept NS records for subdomains.